# How to calculate aggregated summary statistics in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have a Pandas dataframe similar to this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([['red', 'cup', 1.50], ['blue', 'jug', 2.40], ['red', 'cup', 1.75], ['blue', 'cup', 2.30]]),
...                   columns=['colour', 'item', 'price'])
>>> df
  colour item price
0    red  cup   1.5
1   blue  jug   2.4
2    red  cup  1.75
3   blue  cup   2.3
```

What is the most concise way to calculate the summary statistics of the price for each of the possible combinations of colour and item?

Expected output e.g.:

```
colour     item      mean     stdev
red        cup       1.625    0.176
blue       jug       2.4      NA
blue       cup       2.3      NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the way you create the dataframe forced the columns price to string not numeric anymore, since `numpy` `array` only accept one `dtype`

Run:

```
df.price=pd.to_numeric(df.price)
```

---

I will using `describe` after `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['colour','item']).price.describe()# you can add reset_index() here
             count   mean       std  min     25%    50%     75%   max
colour item                                                          
blue   cup     1.0  2.300       NaN  2.3  2.3000  2.300  2.3000  2.30
       jug     1.0  2.400       NaN  2.4  2.4000  2.400  2.4000  2.40
red    cup     2.0  1.625  0.176777  1.5  1.5625  1.625  1.6875  1.75
```

---

Or you can using `agg`

```
df.groupby(['colour','item']).price.agg(['std','mean'])
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the 'color' and 'item' as column headers aligned to the summary stats column names as in the question example?

Comment: reset_index() does it as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` in combination with `.agg` and pass it the `mean` and `std` function:

```
print(df.groupby(['colour', 'item']).agg({'price':['mean', 'std']}).reset_index())

  colour item  price          
                mean       std
0   blue  cup  2.300       NaN
1   blue  jug  2.400       NaN
2    red  cup  1.625  0.176777
```